# How to group multiple conditions in an if statement?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple conditions which I need to check in an `if` statement. Are there any solutions to group conditions? This is my code:

```
if (address1.length === 0 
    && address2.length === 0 
    && city.length === 0 
    && state.length === 0 
    && postalcode.length === 0 
    && country.length === 0){
}
```

Example in C#:

```
string contactinfoGroupValue = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}{3}{4}{5}", address1, address2, city, state, postalcode, country);
if (contactinfoGroupValue == string.Empty) 
{
}
```

Is it possible to follow this pattern in JS? Please help me, thanks.

Comment: That's how you do it.

Comment: you can group conditions with round brackets `()`

Comment: Why don't you just try what you did.

Comment: what you mean by group? You can use round brackets `()` for such kind of grouping by the way.

Comment: what is the concern with it?

Comment: Such like c# :
Example:
string contactinfoGroupValue = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}{3}{4}{5}",address1,address2,city,state,postalcode,country);
if(contactinfoGroupValue == string.Empty){}
I want to group conditions like c# But in jquery.

Answer (score 2):

The literal translation of your C# example to JS would be this:

```
var contactinfoGroupValue = address1 + address2 + city + state + postalCode + country; 
if (contactinfoGroupValue.trim() === '') {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: That's what I expected. Thanks.

Comment: Wait, are you serious? The "proper" way to check if lots of things are 0 is to add them together and compare to the empty string?

Comment: How come we can't just compare the sum to zero?

Comment: You could do that too, I just provided a direct translation of what the C# does.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes I'm not saying this is the 'proper' way to do it, just offering an example for the OP as to what the equivalent of his original C# does. There's certainly nothing wrong with this though, if all you want to do is check any one of those variables contains a value.

Comment: "compare the sum to zero"  - if you also add ` + "" ` then it will always be a string, otherwise the .trim could raise an error.

Comment: Oh, I see. I misread the question as comparing a bunch of numbers to zero, not as checking if multiple strings are empty. My bad.

Comment: they are all string and I think no need to add + "" , Thanks.